# How to split a long string in a variable?

Tags: strings

I would like to split a long string (as in the example below) when this string is in a variable:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\def\parametre{0azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn1azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn2azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn3azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn}
\usepackage{seqsplit}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\seqsplit{\parametre} %not correct
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\seqsplit{0azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn1azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn2azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn3azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn}
%correct
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Doing `\expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\parametre}` will do.